# Tensor Product in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, numpy-ndarray

Can someone please tell me how to do tensor product in python. What I mean is for example, I have 5  (6,1)  (Class: numpy.ndarray) arrays, I need a tensor product of these 5 (6,1) arrays, so that my output will be (6,6,6,6,6) tensor.

Comment: Add an example case.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get that tensor. You have to have 6 arrays instead.
Because for 5 vectors, you can only optain the shape 5x6x5 when doing the product of vectors. This image will have you had an easier generalization
[image]

So, for 6 arrays, I will call it a0,a1...a5. When you multiple 1 to others by applying transpose. In numpy, you can create a loop: `a0*a0.T`,`a0*a1.T`.....

You now will have 6x6 of a0, 6x6 of a1,... 6x6 of a5. Now stack them on top of each other. 6x6x6 of (a0,a2...a5). Now, you need to form others (6x6x6) to form (6x6x6x6) by switching position of a0,a1,...

Continue by doing this for further you can get a (6x6x6x6x6) tensor

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't understand the above inference but, according to Wikipedia, Outer Product or Tensor Product of (6,) and (6,) gives (6,6) tensor. So, with 5 (6,) vectors it gives (6,6,6,6,6) tensor. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product.

Comment: Product of (6,) will go with (6,).T. Then go with (6,) and repeat with (6,).T. Then (6,). It can't be 66666

Comment: But, I got by using einsum (The code in this post).

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work for you?

```
import numpy as np

a1 = np.arange(6)
a2 = np.arange(6)
a3 = np.arange(6)
a4 = np.arange(6)
a5 = np.arange(6)

oo = np.einsum('i,j,k,l,m',a1,a2,a3,a4,a5)
```

Comment: Yeah it works fine. But, I have column vectors shape(6,1) the above code didn't execute with  shape(6,1) column vectors, so I reshaped my vectors to (6,)  then I got the desired output. The above code gives tensor product for 1 dimensional arrays (example: shape(6,). But if I take a 2D shape(1,6) which seems to be same as (6,) but wont generate the same tensor product output. In fact that's how tensor product work.  For example: tensor product of shape(1,6) and shape(1,6) gives (1,6,1,6) output. But tensor product of shape(6,) and shape(6,) gave me desired output with shape(6,6) using einsum.